# OAuth2 oltu client

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, authorization, bearer-token, oltu

I'm building my oauth2-protecet webservice, and a client. For webservice I used spring security implementation, and [used this as example](https://github.com/royclarkson/spring-rest-service-oauth/). For client I'm trying out apache oltu library. Here's my snippet:

```
        OAuthClientRequest request = OAuthClientRequest.tokenLocation
                ("http://localhost:8080/oauth/token")
                .setGrantType(GrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                .setClientId("clientapp")
                .setClientSecret("123456")
                .buildHeaderMessage();

        OAuthAccessTokenResponse oAuthResponse = cli.accessToken(request);

        System.out.println(oAuthResponse.getAccessToken());
```

It does not work. While this

```
curl -X POST -vu clientapp:123456 --data "grant_type=client_credentials&client_secret=123456&client_id=clientapp"  http://localhost:8080/oauth/token
```

works perfectly well. Here's the curl request:

```
POST /oauth/token HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic Y2xpZW50YXBwOjEyMzQ1Ng==
User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
Host: localhost:8080
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 70
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=client_credentials&client_secret=123456&client_id=clientapp
```

as you can see, I used Basic authentication with curl and it worked(even though suggested authentication type is Bearer).

And here's oltu packet:

```
POST /oauth/token HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization: Bearer client_credentials123456clientapp
User-Agent: Java/1.8.0_51
Host: localhost:8080
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 4

null
```

I'm nor sure how bearer authorization is supposed to work, but this packet looks all wrong.

I also tried to use `buildBodyMessage()` and `buildQueryMessage()` instead of `buildHeaderessage()` as was suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20216786/client-credential-grant-type-is-not-properly-sent-with-apache-oltu-client-librar), but it's no good either.

Answer (score 1):

This line doesnt look very healthy:

```
Authorization: Bearer client_credentials123456clientapp
```

I created a test server with Oltu, basically a servlet:

```
        OAuthResponse oauthResponse = OAuthASResponse
            .tokenResponse(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK)
            .setAccessToken(accessToken)
            .setExpiresIn(Integer.toString(expires))
            .setRefreshToken(refreshToken)
            .buildJSONMessage();
        response.setStatus(oauthResponse.getResponseStatus());
        response.setContentType("application/json");
```

And for the client I got:

```
        OAuthClientRequest request = OAuthClientRequest
                .tokenLocation("http://localhost:8083/OltuServer/token")
                .setGrantType(GrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                .setClientId("clientapp")
                .setClientSecret("123456")
                .buildQueryMessage();

        OAuthAccessTokenResponse oAuthResponse = oAuthClient.accessToken(request);

        System.out.println(oAuthResponse.getAccessToken());
```

The main difference from your code is buildQueryMessage(). Using buildHeaderMessage() I get an exception on the server

```
OAuthProblemException {error='invalid_request', description='Missing grant_type parameter value' ... }
```

But I see that Oltu is at version 1.0.1 now while I've been testing on 1.0.0. That version might behave different.

Answer (score 0):

The following appeared to work for me:

```
OAuthClient oAuthClient = new OAuthClient(new URLConnectionClient());
OAuthClientRequest bearerClientRequest = OAuthClientRequest.tokenLocation("http://localhost/rest/auth")
             .setUsername("userid")
             .setPassword("Password01")
             .buildQueryMessage();

bearerClientRequest.setHeader(OAuth.HeaderType.CONTENT_TYPE, "multipart/form-data"); 
OAuthResourceResponse resourceResponse = oAuthClient.resource(bearerClientRequest, OAuth.HttpMethod.POST, OAuthResourceResponse.class);
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little on why that solution worked for you?